# ImageSpecField simply does nothing with django-imagekit in django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, image, django-rest-framework, django-imagekit

I've got the following setup:

```
#models.py
class Image(models.Model):
    original = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    formatted_image = ImageSpecField(source='original', format='JPEG', options={'quality': 90})


#serializers.py
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image

#views.py
class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Image
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
```

According to the ImageKit documentation this should do the trick but literally nothing happens. Not even an error or anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Nothing happens" is rather vague. Is it for instance uploading or viewing images that doesn't work?

Comment: I meet the same question, and open an issue to django-imagekit:https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit/issues/289

Comment: @Joar Leth: By nothing happens I mean literally nothing. No file is being created, no error is being thrown, nothing shows up in the database and to the serializer the fields don't exist.

Comment: @the5fire: thanks for doing that

Comment: @matteok Hi! I am having the same problem. What was your solution?

Comment: Can you try adding processors=[Transpose(),ResizeToFit(50,50)] as a parameter to the ImageSpecField? Hope that does the trick

Answer (score 1):

```
#serializers.py
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    formatted_image = serializers.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = Image
```

This worked for me.